# OnPreferenceChangeListener on triggered when setValue(...) is called

Tags: android, android-preferences, listpreference

Is there any reason why the `onPreferenceChange` for a **ListPreference** method isn't called when you use `setValue(...)` method?

The only time the `onPreferenceChange` is called is when I physically touch the **ListPreference** and make a selection. But when I programmatically change the value of the **ListPreference**, it doesn't get called.

Here's my `setOnPreferenceChangeListener` method definition:

```
public class SettingsActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    ...
    // Load the preferences.xml
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

    // Set the summary for each Preference by reading its defaultValue
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getApplicationContext(), R.xml.preferences, false);

    // Define a change listener
    final String ORIENTATION_KEY = mResources.getString(R.string.pref_quick_orientation_key);
    ListPreference preference = (ListPreference) findPreference(ORIENTATION_KEY);
    preference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object o) {
            // Do something here...
            return true;
        }
    });
    ...
    // Somewhere else in my code, using this code to change the value of the Preference
    final String ORIENTATION_KEY = mResources.getString(R.string.pref_quick_orientation_key);
    ListPreference preference = (ListPreference) findPreference(ORIENTATION_KEY);
    preference.setValue(mResources.getString(R.string.orientation_portrait));
    ...
}
```